# Sum of two independent exponential distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1\sim \exp(\lambda_1)$ and $Y_2\sim \exp(\lambda_2)$ be two independent r.v.'s.

Show that the pdf $p_V(x)$ for their sum $V=Y_1+Y_2$ has the following form
$$p_V(x)=\frac{e^\frac{-v}{\lambda_1}-e^\frac{-v}{\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2};\quad v\ge0$$

#### My attempt:

distribution of $Y_i$,
$$p_{Y_i}(y_i)=\frac{1}{\lambda_i}e^\frac{-{y_i}}{\lambda_i};\quad x\ge0;\quad i=1,2$$

joint distribution of $Y_1$ and  $Y_2$,
$$p_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{\lambda_1\lambda_2}e^{\frac{-{y_1}}{\lambda_1}-\frac{{y_2}}{\lambda_2}};\quad {y_1},{y_2}\ge0$$

Given, $V=Y_1+Y_2$

let $U=Y_2$

So the Jacobian of Transformation is $1$

and hence joint distribution of $V$ and  $U$,
$$p_{V,U}(v,u)=\frac{1}{\lambda_1\lambda_2}e^{\frac{-{v-u}}{\lambda_1}-\frac{{u}}{\lambda_2}};\quad {v},{u}\ge0$$

so the distribution of $v$
$$p_{V}(v)=\int_0^\infty p_{V,U}(v,u)du=\frac{e^\frac{-v}{\lambda_1}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2};\quad v\ge0$$

which doesn't match with the result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We could calculate the cumulative distribution function of $V$, and then differentiate. It is quicker to use the convolution
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(z-t)f_2(t)\,dt,$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the densities of our random variables.

The density function $f_V(v)$ of $V$ is $0$ for $v\lt 0$. So we look only at the case $v\ge 0$.
In our case, since the exponentials have density $0$ to the left of $0$, the actual expression is
$$f_V(v)=\int_{t=0}^v \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_1(v-t)}e^{-\lambda_2 t}\,dt.$$
We are basically integrating $e^{-(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)t}$, which is not difficult.

Comment: In one of my courses `Sampling Distributions` i read there are $4$ methods of finding sampling distributions.One of the methods are `analytical method`. The method can be used when there is only $2$ random variables.According to the method the distribution of the statistic $V=Y_1+Y_2$ is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(z-t)f_2(t)\,dt,\ldots(1)$$. Could you please tell me (1)Why does not the range is $0$ to $\infty$ here? Why have you considered the cdf.If i consider eqn(1),this is pdf.

Comment: (2)Also in my attempt if i consider the range from $0$ to $v$, i come up with the result. I did many convolutions  according to my attempt and `analytical method` with the range of statistic.There i faced no problem.

Comment: (1) I did not use the cdf. Just mentioned that it is an alternate way of finding the density. I actually prefer to do it that way when explaining things to students, since it is has a more conceptual feel. But I chose this time to use the convolution, because it is faster. (Continued)

Comment: (2) We are integrating in principle from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, as I mentioned in the first formula. However, $\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1( v-t)}$ is only correct for the density of $Y_1$ when $v-t\ge 0$. Others like to use *indicator functions* to take care of this problem. It comes down to the same thing.

Comment: I apologize. I haven't understood yet. If $v-t\ge0$ then $v\ge t$. Does it mean $v$ ranges $t$ to $\infty$? Let $X_i\sim^{iid}N(0,1);i=1,2$. When i tried to find the distribution of $Y=X_1+X_2$ by `analytical method` i found 
$$f(y)=\int^{-\infty}_{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(y-x_2)^2}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-{x_2}^2}{2}dx_2$$ 

If i take the range from ${-\infty}$ to $y$, i don't come up with the result. Why will i take the range ${-\infty}$ to ${\infty}$ here?

Comment: For some reason, you are using the density function of the **normal**. Our random variables have **exponential** distribution. With the normal, there is no negativity issue, since the density function is given by a single formula everywhere. With the exponential, the density is $0$ at negative places. Also, $v$ is fixed for this calculation, we are integrating with respect to $t$. Also, $v-t\ge 0$, so $t$ can only range from $0$ to $v$.

Comment: When the case is for $n$ independent random variables,how can i proceed ?

Comment: It is a mess unless the parameters are all equal. Then you get an Erlang distribution, can get to it by induction or (easier!) finding the $n$-th power of the moment generating function of the exponential, and checking against the mgf of the Erlang.