# Sum of exponential random variable with different means

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with pdf's $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and $f(y) = \mu e^{- \mu y}$. What is $\;P \{ X+Y <t \}$ ie what is the cdf of the sum? I know that the distribution is gamma when the parameter is the same, but I'm not sure of a closed form when the parameters are different.

Comment: maybe this would help http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474775/321264

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\large\ t > 0$:
\begin{align}
&\color{0000ff}{\large{\rm P}\braces{x + y < t}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda\expo{-\lambda x}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\mu\expo{-\mu y}\Theta\pars{t - x - y}\,\dd x\,\dd y
=
\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\lambda x}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\mu y}\Theta\pars{\bracks{t - x} - y}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\lambda x}\Theta\pars{t - x}\int^{t - x}_{0}
\expo{-\mu y}\,\dd y\,\dd x
=
\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\lambda x}\Theta\pars{t - x}\,
{\expo{-\mu\pars{t - x}} - 1 \over -\mu}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\lambda\int_{0}^{t}
\bracks{\expo{-\lambda x} - \expo{-\mu t}\expo{\pars{\mu - \lambda}x}}\,\dd x
=
\lambda\bracks{%
{\expo{-\lambda t} - 1 \over -\lambda}
- \expo{-\mu t}{\expo{\pars{\mu -\lambda}t} - 1 \over \mu - \lambda}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lambda\bracks{%
{1 - \expo{-\lambda t} \over \lambda}
+ {\expo{-\mu t} - \expo{-\lambda t} \over \mu - \lambda}}
=
\lambda\,
{\pars{\mu - \lambda}\pars{1 - \expo{-\lambda t}} + \lambda\pars{\expo{-\mu t} - \expo{-\lambda t}}
 \over \lambda\pars{\mu -\lambda }}
\\[3mm]&=
{\pars{\mu - \lambda} - \pars{\mu - \lambda}\expo{-\lambda t}
 +
 \lambda\pars{\expo{-\mu t} - \expo{-\lambda t}} \over \mu -\lambda}
=\color{#0000ff}{\large%
1 - {\mu\expo{-\lambda t} -\lambda\expo{-\mu t} \over \mu - \lambda}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Felix has provided a very nice detailed solution by hand. This type of problem can also be easily solved by automated methods using a computer algebra system ...

By independence, the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is say $f(x,y)$:

[image]

We seek the cdf of the sum, i.e. $P(X+Y<t)$:

[image]

where I am using the `Prob` function from the mathStatica add-on to *Mathematica* to calculate the probability automatically. All done.

Notes:

1. The answer is the same as that obtained by Felix.
2. As formal disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors.

Comment: Good to know this package exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to solve this. By using the Hypoexponential distribution. My answer explaining that distribution more is here.

[Sum of exponential random variables with different parameters - followup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439821/sum-of-exponential-random-variables-with-different-parameters-followup/4437973#4437973)

I quote my note from that answer which is:

> I've used this extensively while trying to calculate the probability
> of the sum of several Exponential random variables with different
> rates being greater than some constant. If you ever need to do that,
> you could use the following:
>
> Let $X_i, i=1..n$ be Exponential random variables with rates
> $\lambda_i, i = 1.. n$ such that $\lambda_i \ne \lambda_j$ for $i \ne
> > j$.
>
> $Y := \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$
>
> Then,
>
> $f(Y>t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,n}e^{-\lambda_it}$
>
> where
>
> $C_{i,n} = \prod_{j\ne i}\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i}$

Therefore, the answer to your question would be:

$With \  t > 0$

$f(X+Y < t) = 1 - f(X+Y > t)$

Here:

$f(X + Y >t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,n}e^{-\lambda_it}$

where

$C_{i,n} = \prod_{j\ne i}\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i}$

**Remark:** $\lambda_1 = \lambda$ and $\lambda_2 = \mu$ per your question

$f(X+Y > t) = \frac{\mu}{\mu-\lambda} e^{-\lambda t} + \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\mu} e^{-\mu t} $

$\therefore f(X+Y < t) = 1-f(X+Y > t) = 1 -\frac{\mu}{\mu-\lambda} e^{-\lambda t} - \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\mu} e^{-\mu t}$

Which is the same as the answer provided by Felix. However, I do prefer the use of the hypoexponential distribution for direct application, in general. It is pretty easy to do by hand as well.