# Lambda and mean of sum of 2 independent exponential random variable

Tags: means, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I have a restaurant with service time being exponentially distributed. Let's say the food-serving time has a mean of 30 minutes, and the checkout time has a mean of 10 minutes.

Would $\lambda$ in this problem $=\frac{1}{30+10}$ or $=\frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: @orange right so I was looking into that as well but Gamma has too many parameters that it confuses me

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635443/sum-of-exponential-random-variable-with-different-means

Comment: If you want the mean, you can get it easily: **the mean of a sum is the sum of the means**, so the mean here is $30+10=40$ minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two independent exponential random variables $X$ and $Y$ with distributions $f_X(t) = \mu e^{-\mu t}$ and $f_Y(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$, the distribution of the sum $X+Y$ is given by the convolution:
\begin{align}
f_{X+Y}(t) &= \int_0^t \mu e^{-\mu \tau}\lambda e^{-\lambda (t-\tau)}\;d\tau\\
&=\lambda\mu e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{-(\mu-\lambda)\tau}\;d\tau\\
&=\frac{\lambda\mu}{\lambda-\mu}\left[e^{-\mu t} - e^{-\lambda t}\right]
\end{align}

The mean is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{\lambda\mu}{\lambda-\mu}\int_0^\infty t\left[e^{-\mu t} - e^{-\lambda t}\right]\;dt&= \frac{\lambda\mu}{\lambda - \mu}\left[\frac{1}{\lambda^2} - \frac{1}{\mu^2}\right]\\
&= \frac{\lambda+\mu}{\lambda\mu}
\end{align}
which in your case is $40$ minutes.