# Sum of gamma distributions and its mean

Tags: statistics, average, gamma-distribution

Could someone explain why the the mean of the 20 independent observations from a unit exponential distribution (the sum of which has a gamma(20,1) distribution) has a gamma(20,20) distribution because I don't seem to understand why this is the case.

Comment: Hint : Use the MGF

Comment: I have not been introduced to the calculation of MGFs which involves a sum of random variables

Comment: The second parameter is presumably a rate parameter.  The mean is $\frac1{20}$ of the sum, i.e. the mean has a rate $20$ times larger than the sum.  This is just scaling

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302101/why-is-the-sample-distribution-the-exponential-distribution-gamma-distributed