# Exponential probabilities problem

Tags: statistics

At a post office the waiting time is exponentially distributed with expected value 5 minutes. Find the probability that 10 clients will have to wait longer than 60 minutes. I know F(x) = 1-e^(-0.2x) but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655302/gamma-distribution-out-of-sum-of-exponential-random-variables

Comment: There's a difference between "10 clients together wait longer than 60" and "10 clients each wait longer than 60". For the former indeed it's a Gamma distribution as saulspatz linked, and for the latter it's just $\left( e^{-0.2 x} \right)^{10}$ with $x = 60$.