# If $X$ is exponential distributed with parameter $\lambda$, how is $\bar{X}/\lambda$ distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

In Davison A.C., Hinkley D.V. - Bootstrap methods and their application It say's $\bar{X}/\lambda$ "has the Gamma distribution with index n and unit mean". I don't understand the sentence. Isn't gamma distribution a generell distribution, including the exponential distribution, Erlang distribution, and chi-squared distribution? And which one would it be here with which parameters?

Thank you.

Comment: Look up the Gamma distribution in Wikipedia to see what terminology the authors are using.

Comment: Your question is missing details but https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655302/321264 should help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$, say, for $x>0$

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}$$

That is equivalent to a Gamma distribution $\Gamma(1;\lambda)$

Let's have $X_1,...,X_n$ iid rv's with the same denisity,

$$\frac{\sum_i X_i}{n \lambda}\sim \Gamma(n;n)$$

That is a Gamma distribution with index $n$ and  mean $\frac{n}{n}=1$

Due to the fact that $n$ is integer, this distribution is a.k.a. Erlang

The proof is trivial using Moment Generating Function and its properties

Comment: Thank you, and these parameters are called  shape and rate? So shape is n and rate is 1?

Comment: $n$ is shape, 1 can be eihter scale or rate; in this case $\lambda$ is scale while rate is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: ok, but if $\lambda$ is unknown, then You don't exactly know how $\bar{X}/\lambda$ is distributed right? Because one parameter is missing, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: As you can see reading my answer, the law of $\frac{\overline{X}}{\lambda}$ is independent by $\lambda$. This is an important result: $\frac{\overline{X}}{\lambda}$ is a rv depending on the parameter but with a law that is independent by the parameter: it is a pivotal quantity so you can use it to estimate the unknown parameter :)

Comment: Sorry i don't get it. How is $\bar{X}/\lambda$ independent of $\lambda$ if it follows a distribution with one parameter being $1/\lambda$

Comment: If you read well what i wrote, I said that $\frac{\overline{X}}{\lambda}\sim \Gamma(n;n)$, INDEPENDENT BY $\lambda$. If  you do not get it do all the calculation to get this result. It is very easy and you can get it with MGF properties or with Fundamental Transformation Theorem

Comment: Further more: if you use the following quantity: $\frac{2\sum_i X_i}{\lambda}\sim \chi_{(2n)}^2$ so you can use the tables to estimate your parameter

Comment: ok, so the parameter "rate" of the gamma distribution which is $1/\lambda$ has absolutely no meaning or what?

Comment: come on....initially you have a distribution (neg exp) with an unknown parameter to estimate....with the help of your textbook you have a new rv that depends on the n observations (observable data), on the parameter, whose distribution is independent by the parameter....this is the best scenario you can have to do inference on $\lambda$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Im about to flip out. I better go to bed and give it a try again tomorrow.

Comment: I am here, if you need help. I suggest you to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity before try again, to understand what  a pivotal quantity is

Comment: (+1) Just fixed a minor typo. But also, don't you mean gamma with shape $n$ and _rate_ = $n$ in displayed eqn?

Comment: If you're estimating the mean μ of a normal population with mean μ and SD σ, then you might take the mean $\bar X$ of n obs. to estimate μ. Then the dist'n of $\bar X$ is normal with mean μ and SD $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ Also, $\bar X−μ$ has a normal dist'n with mean 0 and SD $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$. (No mention of μ.) // Similarly, if you take n obs. from an exponential population with mean λ, then you might use $\bar X$ to estimate λ. But here, $\bar X/λ$ is gamma dist'd with parameters shape=n and _rate_ n. (No mention of λ). –

Answer (score 0):

**Comment continued:**  Let $n=10; \lambda =\mathrm{scale} = 2.$ Vector `a` has 100,000 sample averages. Simulation in R.

```
set.seed(2020);  n = 10;  scale=2
a = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(n,1/scale)))  
 # In R 2nd param = rate
mean(a); var(a)
[1] 1.998913    # aprx E(A) = 2
[1] 0.3998701   # aorx Var(A) = 4/10
mean(a/scale)
[1] 0.9994563   # aprx 1
var(a/scale)
[1] 0.09996752  # aprx 1/10


hist(a/scale, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dgamma(x, n, n), add=T, col="red")
 # density of gamma with shape=n, rate=n
```

[image]