# Understanding the sum of iid exp(1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X,Y$ $\sim$ $i.i.d.$ $exp(1)$, $X+Y$ $\sim$ $Gamma(2,1)$. I know how to arrive at this using sum of MGFs, but I'm wondering if there's an intuitive way to understand this.

Comment: Use a [convolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). And see the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655302/463578)

Comment: This question is very vague. What kind of "intuitive way" are you looking for?

Comment: It's hard to be precise, but sometimes [you want "more" than a proof](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2010-06-20).

Answer (score 1):

A link between the two distributions is the Poisson process.

Exponential(1) is the time until one arrival in a Poisson process with rate parameter 1.

Gamma(2, 1) is the time until there are two arrivals in a Poisson process with rate parameter 1.

These can be derived by themselves (for example, I ta'd a course where this was showed by using the cdf. Roughly referencing the notes again, let $X$ be a Poisson process with rate 1 so the arrivals in time period of length t is $Exp(t)$. Let T be the time until the 2nd arrival. We have $F(t) = P(T\le t)= 1-P(T>t)=1-P(X_{0,t}=0\text{ or } 1)=1-\sum_{i=0}^1 \frac{e^{-t}t^i}{i!}$. If you take the derivative of this, you are supposed to get the Gamma(2, 1) pdf. You can do the same thing for the time until 1 arrival.)

Because "the time until 2 arrivals" is "the time until one arrival plus the time until one arrival," Gamma(2,1) [time until 2 arrivals] = Exp(1) [time until an arrival] + Exp(1) [time until an arrival]