# $\Bbb P(E_0+E_1>x)$ where $E_0,E_1$ are exponential random variables

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

Let $E_0\sim$ Exp($\lambda$) and $E_1\sim$ Exp($1$) be independetn r.v. and let $\lambda>1$ and $x>0$.

I am not sure if the bounds of the following integral should be $(0,1)$ or $(0,\infty)$ $$\Bbb P(E_0+E_1>x)=\int\limits_0^1 \Bbb P(E_0>x-s)f_{E_1}(s)ds$$ where $f_{E_1}$ is the density function of $E_1$

Comment: Why do you think the bounds should be $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @Henry But $s$ is the dummy variable

Comment: Oh the right bound should be $x$ right? I realize now that $1$ doesn't make sense

Comment: $P(E_0 >x-s)$ is not $0$ when $x-s$ is negative. It is $1$. So don't ignore $s >x$.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474775/sum-of-two-independent-exponential-distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\int_x^{\infty} e^{-s}ds+\int_0^{x}\int_{x-s}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx e^{-s} ds$. [$s>x$ cannot be ignored in the computation].

Answer (score 0):

The integral in theory should be over  $(-\infty,\infty)$

In practice this reduces to an integral over $[0,x]$ plus another over $(x, \infty)$ since

- $f_{E_1}(s)=0$ for $s \lt 0$ and
- $\Bbb P(E_0>x-s) = 1$ for $s \gt x$

Comment: Wrong answer. The probability in the last line is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - Corrected - thank you